# Encoding a RAW video

Tags: windows, linux, video-editing

I'm looking for a simple software to convert from RAW video to an encoded format. The ideal candidate will:

- make good use of multiple CPU cores;
- have the possiblity of splitting into multiple files, with the times specified in a GUI;
- encode using Ogg [Theora](http://www.theora.org/).

It can be either Windows or Linux.

Comment: RAW video?  Do you mean recording from a tuner or camera or are you saying you have RAW digital video files?  If you have files, what format are the in?

Comment: I'm downloading the video files from my Sony Handicam dcr-hc51e.

Answer (score 1):

It's a while since I've used it, but I think Handbrake may well fit your requirements: [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)

The only area where I'm not sure it'll meet your requirements is how it handles splitting into multiple output files. But it does support Theora encoding, and I think it can make use of multiple CPUs/cores.